# After changing path nano doesn't work

Tags: linux, centos, vi, nano

After i did change server ~bash_profile for PATH to my Java i cannot use nano or vip anymore.

I actully don't know how to change it back, while i cannot edit it with nano or vi anymore.

What can i do?

```
 -bash: ano: command not found
 root@s [~]# nano
 -bash: nano: command not found
 root@s [~]# pacstrap -i /mnt base base-devel
 -bash: pacstrap: command not found
 root@s [~]# nano /etc/timezon
 -bash: nano: command not found
 root@s [~]# nano /etc/timezone
 -bash: nano: command not found
 root@s [~]# vi
 -bash: vi: command not found
 root@s [~]# vi
 -bash: vi: command not found
 root@s [~]# nano ~/.bash_profile
 -bash: nano: command not found
 root@s [~]# vi ~/.bash_profile
 -bash: vi: command not found
 root@s [~]#
```

Comment: can you show the bash_profile contents?

Comment: Funny - no, as i said, i cannot use nano or vi to show content of the files, or else i could edit it.

Comment: Try `/bin/nano` or `/usr/bin/nano`... or `/bin/rm ~/.bash_profile` (and relogin)

Answer (score 6):

You most likely overrode your path to just java instead of appending to it.

**WRONG**:

```
export PATH=/opt/somewhere/java/bin
```

**RIGHT**:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/somewhere/java/bin
```

to fix this, do

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

...and you should have vi and nano back in your path.

Comment: I did the last. When i then use nano  ~/.bash_profile the file is empty, and says: "   File: /root/.bash_profile "

Comment: This was very helpful.  +1